# Best-of-breed JavaScript datatable widget/library

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datatable, yui

I've used a couple datatable widgets in the past, including [YUI2's](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/), and I'm curious to know if there's a perceived frontrunner out there. I'm excited for [jQuery Grid](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/02/unleash-the-grid/), but I haven't seen anything since it was announced.

What I'd like to see in a datatable provider:

- Can consume JSON arrays of arbitrary objects' key-value pairs; YUI2's ability to declare a schema to map these objects to columns does well (even though rest of the API is a bit verbose, clunky).
- Provides an ability to filter via text fields
- Supports client-side pagination (an ability to swap out with server-side pagination would be a plus).
- Supports a means to customize the presentation/format of cells with arbitrary HTML (links, images, etc.)

With no further guidance, I'm likely to look into [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and [YUI3 DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/datatable/). Recommendations?

Comment: Datatables is pretty comprehensive - see http://mvcjquerydatatables.apphb.com/ for an example with ajax filtering, sorting, custom cells, excel exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't investigated the YUI3 yet but from what I hear it's vastly improved from 2. It might sound heretical but have you thought of rolling your own? I've really been digging KnockoutJS, and they have a simple example of a DataGrid with paging. I'm sure it could be extended pretty easily. http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html

I've also used jQuery DataTables in a production environment. Admittedly, it was a simple use case but it didn't seem to present any problems.

Comment: this is the path I'm currently going down and I like it a lot. It doesn't have the features I'd like baked in, but everything else I spiked (jqGrid & SlickGrid) had relatively poor documentation and either a large footprint or a lot of dependencies I didn't want to marry myself to.

Comment: knockoutjs is a mvvm model built on a fixed timer - really not good for web development and user experience at all

JQuery DataTables is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

I cast my vote for [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php), I found it really easy to use, and it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Slickgrid, and staying away from DataTables. In using DataTables, I ran into a number of problems syncing the datastore with the view. I also didn't like the hungarian notation on the API's interface. Doesn't seem like it would be a big deal, but it gets to you after a while.

Slickgrid has been the best I've used so far, out of jqGrid, Datatables and Slickgrid.

EDIT: after spending more time with all the options, I ended up modifying SlickGrid to hide some of the details and allow for more styling options...

So "modified slickgrid" ended up being my choice. Pretty happy with it, although I think there's lots of room for competition.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI beats both of these hands down.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

Answer (score 1):

DataTables looks promising. seems to be powerful and flexible

http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Comment: datatables is a giant bloated mess IMO

Answer (score 1):

Handsontable: A minimalistic Excel-like data grid editor for HTML, JavaScript & jQuery

http://handsontable.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2

The ExtJS grid is something you want to look into.  ExtJS is a nice framework, they just released and their api's are quite complete yet but once their done I'm sure they'll be top notch.

Comment: Huge footprint for just a grid.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out Doby Grid: http://dobyjs.com/#grid
It's based on SlickGrid but with many additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Webix Datatale as it provides all the above mentioned features. You can check the demo and read more about it here: http://webix.com/widget/datatable/.