# filering PrimeUI datatable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, primefaces, filtering

Does anyone know how to filter a PrimeUI datatable?? i am using angular and PrimeUI, in the html i have the text field that according to it i want to filter my data table

```
$('#table').puidatatable({
        caption: 'my tbl',
        paginator: {
            rows: 9
        },
        columns: [
            {field:'name', headerText: 'name', sortable:true} ,
            {field:'age', headerText: 'age', sortable:true},
             {field:'id', headerText: 'ID', sortable:true}
        ],
        datasource: myarray         
        ,
        selectionMode: 'single',
        rowSelect: function(event, data) {
            some code            
        }});
    $('#messages').puigrowl();
```

and in my html :

```
  <input id="basic" name="basic" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment, filtering is not available on [PrimeUI Datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/datatable.html). It's not mentioned anywhere on the page. I suggest you consider other  - [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797547/best-of-breed-javascript-datatable-widget-library).

Comment: It will be available in 2.1 release.

Comment: @CagatayCivici 2.1 is released but the feature is not available yet. Maybe in 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no support to filter Prime UI data table but still you can filter your data table from server side like i have implemented prime ui data table with custom search. I send one parameter from search field if that is empty i return all data if search filed contains some data i return filtered data though this i achieve the filter functionality

```
<!--input filed for search -->
   <input type="text" name ="abc" id="input-filter" onkeypress="javascript:gridSearch();"/>

function searchToJSON(){
    return JSON.stringify({
        "input-filter": document.getElementById('input-filter').value,
        });
}


gridSearch = function() {      
       var searchUrl= 'searchUrl';
       $('#table').puidatatable({  
       lazy: true,
        paginator: {  
            rows: 5  
        },  
        columns: [
            {field:'abc', headerText: 'abc', sortable:true},
            {field:'xyz', headerText: 'xyz', sortable:true}
        ],  
        datasource: function(callback) {  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: searchUrl, 
                datatype : "application/json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data:searchToJSON(), // supply json fields and return filtered data from server accoring to your requirements
                context: this,  
                success: function(response) { 
                    callback.call(this, response.data);  
                }  
            });  
        }           ,
    });  
};
```